# Why navmesh can detect all subtilities of my model while meshcollier can't?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just made a quick terrain in sketchup to test an fps system I made.

[image]

The navmesh fits perfectly my model (which is imported in one block) but I made some research and couldn't find a way to hade a clean collider following the model so my Player could navigate normally through it. Isn't there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your collider to be a concave mesh.
Untick the "Convex" settings on the mesh collider

Comment: Well the green borders you see in the screenshot corresponds to the "convex ticked" generated mesh collier...

Comment: You need to untick it. Convex is for objects with no cavities (for instance, a ball) Concave is for objects with indents, such as a cup, or a donut. Convex is the default because it's more efficient to calculate